# AngularJS: Issue with http chain calling and NodeJS: issue with using variable in multiple http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, variables

I have a get call and a post call in my node.js file, both of which use the same variable that I initialized to an empty string outside these calls. In the post call, I set the variable, while in the get call, I return the value of the variable to my clientside angularjs that is requesting the value. In my angularjs file, I make the post call first and then the get call, which means the value should be set and should be available when the get call is issued and returns. Here's what I'm doing:

NodeJS

```
var myUrl= "";
app.post('/post', function(req, res){
   myUrl = res.url;
}); 

app.get('/get, function(req, res){
    res.json({result: myUrl});
});
```

AngularJS:

```
var promise = $http.post('/post')
        .then(function(response){

            return $http.get('/get');

        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data.result);
        });
```

I've tried AngularJS promise chain calling but it still doesn't work. The problem I'm having is that when I make the get call in the first round of requests, the url variable hasn't been set yet even though the post call has been already issued, so the get call returns an empty string. In the second round of requests, the get call returns the value that has been set from the first post call, and so on and so forth.

Any ideas on why this is happening and suggestions on how to solve this issue so that the get call returns the value that is set in the post call in the same round of requests (the get call is issued when the post call is done)? I'm fairly new to NodeJS so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there any mechanism that guarantees POST arrive before GET in your Angular client ? If not, the result quite make sense ,because its asynchronous.

Comment: @RayonDabre  I've updated my code in the post, it's for a url returned from the server. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Are you issuing `get` call after `post` success callback ?

Comment: Yea, I tried putting get call inside the success callback on client side and on server side. No luck..

Comment: Your server side code is find.just make sure that in your client side code the GET isn't issues until the POST completes

Comment: Shouldn't it be `req.url`?

Comment: @Xeijp Updated the post with my AngularJS code that does chain calling, which is supposed to execute the http calls one at a time, still doesn't work tho :(

Comment: in post route why it is `myUrl = res.url;` ? shouldn't it be `myUrl = req.url;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your angular code is fine, though you have missed a small thing. I modified your code and tested, it works as expected.

Solution:

```
var myUrl= "";
app.post('/post', function(req, res){
   //not res.url
   myUrl = req.url;
   //Your missed this!
   res.status(204).end();
}); 

app.get('/get, function(req, res){
    res.json({result: myUrl});
});
```

Explanation:

Without `res.status(204).end();` or `res.send({})` or `res.json({})` the `/post` call just updates the url and then hangs there and does nothing, never returns and will eventually timeout. So when next time you call `/get` you get the URL.

You must consider the fact that all your route handlers are just `middleware` and you must generate a response or execute `next` middleware.

In your case, you wanna handle the request and want to end there, it was required to send some response. so we sent `res.status(204).end();`, meaning: `There is no content to serve`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm. I see what you're saying. I changed my code and added the missing line, but it still doesn't work. I made some print statements in both calls and it seems like the print statement in the get call is being printed out first, and then the print statement in the post call. In this case, I'm not sure if this is client side issue or server side issue.

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it! I found out that if I just send the data back in the first post call, I don't have to make another get call to retrieve the url back. Thanks for the help! :)